# Google analytics measure protocol event tracking stopped working

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have a script which runs on my server every time and event happens. This randomly has stopped working on the 1st/2nd July. I have checked the Analytics change history and the last change was April.

The code has not changed and i'm not getting any errors from the request.

```
data = {
    'v': '1',
    't': 'event',
    'tid': 'UA-XXXXXX-X',
    'cid': '11111111.2222222',
    'ec': 'ccccc',
    'ea': 'aaaaa',
    'el': 'lllll',
    'ev': 50
}

response = requests.post('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect', data=data)
response.raise_for_status()
```

This returns no errors and has a status code of 200, but just does not show up anymore in analytics. I also tried the measure hit builder tool with the same params and it sent 2 hits successfully.

How can I debug this?

Comment: what happens if you send it to 'http://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect'  just open the link in a web browser as a http get easiest way.  It should return some json  What type of an account is it web?

Comment: Wow, never knew about debug. It's a web account. I get an exception requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno bad handshake] [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')]

Comment: The normal end point doesn't respond with errors it just ignores your request.   its a curse.   What's the error?

Comment: build up your request as a http get. I am not sure that debug takes posts.

Comment: Hmmm, yep seems it. Thanks for the debug url. Should help me solve this now. :)

Comment: GET gives the same SSL error. I probably need to use pyOpenSSL.

Comment: The hit looks valid from here probably server issue

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, i'll try and fix my server.

Comment: also fun https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and send your request to

```
google-analytics.com/debug/collect
```

This will help you debug the problem.   The request you are sending appears to be valid.